# How to install project using git and grunt

Tags: node.js, git, gruntjs, npm, npm-install

I have never used grunt but I am trying to install project using github.

They ask me to install assets using grunt. I read documentation on grunt website and have installed the grunt using npm install -g grunt-cli. I have also installed node.js.

I already ran `npm install -g grunt-cli bower` and it runs without problem but "npm install" fails with many errors.

I would be grateful if somebody can guide me how to install the assets using grunt using a dummy "github project."

Thanks

Comment: What are the errors that you get? maybe its proxy issues?

Comment: npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Rosh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/....../nodecast-js.git C:\Users\Rosh\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\https-github-com-......-nodecast-js-git-ce34d80a: undefined .. I have dotted the main git address

Comment: what is git protocol? http? https? git?

Comment: @codeWizard it is http://

Comment: Try to run `npm cache clean` and then `npm install` again

Comment: @codeWizard didn't work

Comment: Does the project you are trying to download has a package.json?

Comment: @codeWizard yes it does.

Comment: Make a example here https://c9.io/ so we can see your code